# How to print the result of a class without the class name?

Tags: python

The following class declares variables and their values.

```
class StaticTileType(Enum):
    CHASM = 0
    EMPTY = 1
    GRASS = 2
    EMPTY_WELL = 3
    WALL = 4
    DOOR = 5

print(StaticTileType(4))
```

This code prints `StaticTileType.DOOR`. How can I print/return `DOOR` only, without the module name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` attribute of the `Enum`

```
print(StaticTileType(4).name)
```

Result:

```
WALL
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to create object of that class and access values

obj= StaticTileType(4)

print(obj.DOOR)